# How do I get jQuery validation to check all fields with a common prefix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am dynamically generating a series of fields based on a previous selection. As I do not know how many fields will be generated I cannot hard-code the validation script to check them.

However, all the fields that are generated will have an ID in a common format. For example,

- A score field all start with id="score_uniqueValue"
- A stanine field all start with id="stanine_uniqueValue"
- A 'years' field all start with id="years_uniqueValue"
- A 'months' field all start with id="months_uniqueValue"

Is there a way to adapt my jQuery validation script to check all fields in the form with that prefix and run a standard rule for it? This is the script I use for checking one individual field.

```
class OpAuthSignIn {
/*
 * Init Sign In Form Validation
 *
 */
static initValidationScore() {
    jQuery('.js-validation-scores').validate({
        errorClass: 'invalid-feedback animated fadeInDown',
        errorElement: 'div',
        errorPlacement: (error, e) => {
            jQuery(e).parents('.form-group > div').append(error);
        },
        highlight: e => {
            jQuery(e).closest('.form-group').removeClass('is-invalid').addClass('is-invalid');
        },
        success: e => {
            jQuery(e).closest('.form-group').removeClass('is-invalid');
            jQuery(e).remove();
        },
        rules: {
            'score': {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 3,
                number: true
            },
            'stanine': {
                required: false,
                maxlength: 1,
                number: true
            },
            'years': {
                required: false,
                maxlength: 2,
                number: true
            },
            'months': {
                required: false,
                maxlength: 2,
                number: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            'score' : 'Enter a valid 3 digit standardised score.',
            'stanine' : 'Enter a valid stanine between 1 and 9.',
            'years' : 'The ability age year value needs to be valid.',
            'months' : 'Enter a valid month between 1 and 11.'
        }
    });
}

/*
 * Init functionality
 *
 */
static init() {
    this.initValidationScore();
}
}// Initialize when page loads
jQuery(() => { OpAuthSignIn.init(); });
```

Comment: You'll need to use a comma-separated list of partial attribute selectors. Any reason you're not putting a common class on those? Hard-coded IDs are a last resort, in my opinion, even if they're not dynamic.

Comment: If those duplicates don't cover your questions, please revise to be more specific. Asking about your entire script is a bit broad for our format.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've looked at the similar questions but I do not know how apply it to this validation script. I do have a comma separated list being saved to a hidden field on the page which stores all the unique IDs. There is only ever going to be about 3 ID values, This is in a list  hidden field called testnameIDlist.